# To find lim of $\sqrt{(9e^{2n}+2020e^n+2019)}-\sqrt{(9e^{2n}-2018e^n+2017)}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{(9e^{2n}+2020e^n+2019)}-\sqrt{(9e^{2n}-2018e^n+2017)}$$

I have tried to multiply by $a+b$ to get $a^2 - b^2$, but I realized it does not simplify further. What is the best way I can approach this problem?

Comment: hmm perhaps you're still on the right track. Note that
$$
a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)
$$
and therefore
$$
a-b = \frac{a^2 - b^2}{a+b}
$$

Comment: also, I would do
$$
\sqrt{
9e^{2n} + 2020e^n  + 2019
} = 3e^n \sqrt{
1 + 
\frac{2020e^n}{9e^{2n}} +
\frac{2019}{9e^{2n}}
}
$$
and the same for the other term.

Comment: Ohh jesus! Did I just add the title of the question in the question itself.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you say it does not simplify further? When you multiply and divide by "$a+b$" you get

$$
\lim \dfrac{4038e^{n}+2}{\sqrt{9 e^{2n}+2020 e^n+2019}+\sqrt{9 e^{2n}-2018e^n+2017}} = \lim\dfrac{4038+2e^{-n}}{\sqrt{9+202e^{-n}+2019e^{-2n}}+\sqrt{9-2018e^{-n}+2017e^{-2n}}} = \frac{4038}{6} = 673.
$$